# Looping through load functions - callback once all have completed?

Tags: jquery

When looping through load functions, is it possible to run a callback once all have completed?

It appears all load functions are running simultaneously, so I am having trouble running a callback when the longest of the loads completes.

```
$.each( preloadedArray[entryId], function( key, value ) {
  
    preloadedArray[entryId][key].on('load', function() {
            
        // loaded

    });
    
    // When all have loaded...?
    
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classical jQuery way of doing this is to collect `$.Deferred` objects - one per async function call - into an array and wait for them to resolve.

```
var pendingResults = [];

$.each(preloadedArray[entryId], function( key, value ) {
    var result = $.Deferred();
    pendingResults.push(result.promise());

    preloadedArray[entryId][key].on('load', function() {
        // ...do work...

        // loaded
        result.resolve();
    });
});

$.when.apply($, pendingResults).done(function () {
    console.log("all done");
});
```

In modern JS you can use `new Promise()` and `Promise.all()` in the same spirit. Rewritten as a `.map()` to promises, but functionally equivalent to the above:

```
var pendingResults = preloadedArray[entryId].map(value => {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        value.on('load', function() {
            // ...
            // loaded
            resolve();
        });
    });
});

Promise.all(pendingResults).then(function () {
    console.log("all finished");
});
```

Comment: Beautiful way to explain thumbs up for that.